# Web Part connection Server Render in combination JS link not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I am using a connection with filter to a list view webpart of a Task list. (SPO) This didn't work because of a known MS issue. (see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/web-parts/list-view-web-part-not-filter-values)

I have to check "Server Render" in the Web Part settings and the filter does work.

However I also use a JS link reference in this view. This doesn't work anymore when I check "Server Render".

Is it possible to have both work? Or isn't this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to have both this work since JS Link is Client-Side Rendering.

Similar issue for your reference:[enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c9ea536b-b0e2-4460-89ac-62af710f1526/issues-with-quotserver-renderquot-option-when-using-js-link?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: Was afraid so... Thank you.